# MEF and DirectoryCatalog

Tags: c#, .net, ioc-container, mef

Is there a way to safely use DirectoryCatalog to handle if the directory doesn't exist?

Here a code example of how my container is setup:

```
    //Create an assembly catalog of the assemblies with exports
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
        new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()),
        new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.Load("My.Second.Assembly")),
        new DirectoryCatalog("Plugins", "*.dll"));

    //Create a composition container
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

But an exception is thrown if the directory doesn't exist, and I would like to ignore that error.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just check for the directory existence before setting up the `AggregateCatalog`?

Comment: I would, but there seems to be some nice logic built into DirectoryCatalog for getting the correct path (not simply the current directory).  Anyone know what it uses?  Assembly.Location?

Comment: I commented on the answer below, but I'll also mention it here... you should not rely on checking for the directories existence alone. You should take into account any IOExceptions you wish to handle (i.e. if the Directory does not exist, or if the files are locked, or UAT, etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently not if an exception is thrown.  Just create the directory prior to running the MEF container setup and then no error will be thrown.

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833448.aspx):

> The path must be absolute or relative to [`AppDomain.BaseDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx).

PsuedoCode to do a directory check:

```
    string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins");

    //Check the directory exists
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    //Create an assembly catalog of the assemblies with exports
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
        new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()),
        new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.Load("My.Other.Assembly")),
        new DirectoryCatalog(path, "*.dll"));

    //Create a composition container
    _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

Comment: See my comment above.  What method does DirectoryCatalog use to expand the full path?

Comment: It's either absolute or relative to System.AppDomain.BaseDirectory.

Comment: Marked you as answer.  I updated your code in your answer to what I used.

Comment: You should never rely on a race condition check such as `Directory.Exists(path)`. Between that call and the next call the directory might not exist. Instead, use exception handling to catch a possible exception and handle it appropriately... see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9003962/347172

Comment: Directory.CreateDirectory will fail on the small chance that the directory gets created in between the exists check and createdirectory call.  So, yes, there should be a try catch block around this code or somewhere in the call stack.

Comment: @JonRaynor Did you ever take the time to read docs and do testing with `Directory.CreateDirectory`? From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): “If the directory already exists, this method does not create a new directory, but it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing directory.” From testing: calling `Directory.CreateDirectory()` doesn’t fail if the directory exists. Your whole check is pointless.

Comment: @m-y You’re right that the `Directory.Exists(path)` is superfluous. But once that’s removed, there is still a race condition. The actual race condition is that the directory may be deleted between the `Directory.CreateDirectory()` and `new DirectoryCatalog()`. Though just letting the application fail at this point might be better than potentially entering an infinite loop trying to recreate the directory if it keeps disappearing. If it keeps disappearing, you have a different problem—a problem with the program’s hosting environment ^^.