# Is there a way to instantly check whether a directory is in use?

Tags: c#, windows, file, filesystems

I want to move a directory and all of its subdirectories with Directory.Move.

Before I do that, however, I want to check whether any of the files and subfiles in the directory and its subdirectories are being used by other processes.

Then, before the move, I'd like to lock the directory to other processes, so I can be sure that Directory.Move won't throw any exceptions.

What is the best way to accomplish that?

I would like to avoid checking for the usage of the individual files file by file, because the fact that the file isn't used when the software checks for it does not mean that it won't be used when the movement process starts.

Comment: I added a Windows tag. Can you be more specific about which version of Windows you are working on?

Comment: I'm on windows 7, but I'd rather for this to work on as many windows versions as possible

Comment: I can't think of a realistic scenario where this could fail due to locks on files.  It is not how Windows works, renaming a locked file is not a problem.  If you are actually moving the directory to another drive then, yes, *that* could be a problem.  So use Copy() instead and delete afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to lock the folder (+ sub folders) so you'll always end up with a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and there is no guarantee that there will be no exception.

There is always the possibility that something changes in between the check and the move so things can go wrong.

Just try to move the folder and retry later if not succeeding.

See also: [Delphi: Check whether file is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502996/delphi-check-whether-file-is-in-use) (this is a similar question, just ignore the Delphi part)

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You can put your File opteration into a try .. catch block
and catch `IOException`.

#### Sample

```
try 
{
   // try to move
} 
catch (System.IO.IOException ex) 
{
   // file used by another process or other IO Exception
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - IOException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx)

Comment: Considering you're using .Net 4+ you can also use `Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5)).ContinueWith((o) => WatchDogOnCreated(this, fileSystemEventArgs));` in combination with your code (placed in the catch-clause - it is indeed a very critical code, but I've found this to be working. At least it's a workaround.